# The routing delay is 0 ns in quartus chipplanner

Tags: intel-fpga, ltdc

I designed a program about TDC. However, I found the routing delay is 0 ns when I check its timming by Timequest. Shown below, the Tco is 0.073 ns, but the routing delay is 0 ns.

[image]

Obviously, there is no delay between the adjacent LEs. In this case, the timing report illustrates many slacks shown figure below.
[image]

I want to have it working reliably, and make it clear whether the zero ns affected by those slacks.

Any ideas?

Comment: With any luck, that 0 ns uses timing references that are offset for adjacent logic slices, so that the inter slice can be taken as 0 because the slice I/O time has been padded. But what you show does not engender confidence!

Comment: In fact, I have confirmed that the 0 ns routing delay has no connection with the huge slack in earlier this evening. And now, I am more concerned about why the 0 ns routing delay persist. You are right, the slice I/O time has been padded. But in this case the delay between LABs should bigger than those between LEs. Therefore, the routing delay is assuredly wrong. I have been stumped until now and didn't know what else to do...